# In Python can I change the structure of a class at runtime?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

In Python you can add new instance variables to an instance of a class at runtime like this...

```
>> class Foo:
>>     def __init__(self, bar):
>>         self.bar = bar
>> 
>> f = Foo()
>> setattr(f, "baz", "spam")
>> f.baz
"spam"
```

...but it only has effect on the instance `f` not the class `foo`.

```
>> x = Foo()
>> x.baz
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

Is there a way to add the new instance variable `baz` to the class `Foo`, so that all new instances of that class have the new variable?

Comment: Usually this is considered bad practice, against the principle of least surprise.

Comment: The program will dynamically build objects based on input, and then return the final version of the object when complete. So the object the user will use should reflect whatever data-structure was the input, hopefully preserving the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the attribute of the class instead of the instance.

```py
setattr(Foo, "baz", "spam")
```

Output

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, bar):
...         self.bar = bar

>>> f = Foo('bar')
>>> setattr(Foo, "baz", "spam")
>>> f.baz
'spam'
>>> f2 = Foo('bar')
>>> f2.baz
'spam'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only thing to note is that when you add the new attribute to `Foo`, all previous instances will use the new attribute with the same value assigned to `Foo`. Any update to `Foo`'s value will be replicated in the instances until the instances are explicitly set.